# Keyboard randomly not working in different applications

Tags: keyboard, windows-10

I'm experiencing random "disconnects" of my keyboard for several days now.
However the keyboard doesn't really disconnect but I'm not able to use it in different applications.
For example I was working in Visual Studio 2015 for some hours, then decided to play some rounds of Counterstrike Global Offensive, then switched back to continue working on the VS15 project. Unfortunately I wasn't able to enter any characters in the IDE anymore.
The error seems to appear randomly and doesn't seem to be bound to my usage behaviour as it can appear at any time and in any workflow. Apart from that it seems that only one application is affected by this issue because any other applications accept any keyboard input as usual.
I tried to physically disconnect my keyboard and reconnect it. Unfortunately it only worked once but it seems not to be a fix for the issue.
The only way to ensure that everything works again is to reboot the system.
I'm using Windows 10 Professional 64bit and my keyboard connects via a PS/2 connector and a USB connector for USB passthrough.
This issue only appeared on Windows 10 so far.

Does anyone of you know what could be the cause or where to look to get further information about this?

Comment: Do you mean you are using a PS2 keyboard with a USB adapter to connect it? Have you tried a different keyboard? Is your BIOS up to date? Are there drivers specific to the keyboard?

Comment: No, my keyboard has two connectors. One PS/2 connector and a USB connector. I guess the USB connector is for the integrated USB hub and led lightning. BIOS is up to date. I haven't tried a different keyboard yet but because this issue occurs on my laptop too I think it's not caused by my keyboard.